# attempting to script r commands to run

Tags: r

I have files in two different directories that I would like to merge the same files.

for example:

in c:/data1, I have files like this:

teamA.Rdata, teamB.RData, teamC.RDate

in c:/data2 I have the same files:

teamA.Rdata, teamB.RData, teamC.RDate

The file names are the same but the content of the files are different. I like to write an r script to combile files with the same names. For example, I would like to merge teamA.RData file locate in C:/data1 and c:/data2 directories:

I have written this piece of code:

```
for (i in dir("c:/data1", pattern = "^team"))

     {

      print(i)

      for (r in dir("c:/data2", pattern= "^team"))

        {

             print(r)
             if(i==r) {
             print("yesssssssssssssssssssssss")
             }
         }
   }
```

I put this line of code to R console, I get a print out. However, when I tried to run this in via an rscript, I dont get anything even though I have print statements in the code. Is there something that I have to do in rscript to make this happen?

Comment: you really need to tag this question better.  Start with the programming language your using.

Comment: Please, tell us the out of `dir("c:/data1", pattern = "^team")`, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do the paths exist? Do the regexes match? Try `pattern=".*team"` or `pattern="*team"`.

```
> system('touch hello')
> system('touch helloo')
> system('touch hellooo')
> system('ls')
1  2  hello  helloo  hellooo
> list.files('.',pattern='hello*')
[1] "hello"   "helloo"  "hellooo"
> list.files('.',pattern='hello.*')
[1] "hello"   "helloo"  "hellooo"
```

You can read in the history how you can concatenate files.